# Distance between two subsets of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, $a\in E$ and $0<r$. Suppose $x\in E$
> such that $x\not\in B(a;r)$. Then  $$d(a,x)-r\leq d(x,B(a;r)),$$ where
> $d(x,B(a;r)):=\inf_{d(a,y)<r}d(x,y)$.

We simply have to show that $d(a,x)-r$ is a lower bound of the family $(d(x,y))_{d(a,y)<r}$. Let $y\in B(a; r)$. Then $d(a, y)<r$: i.e. $-r<-d(a, y)$ and $d(a,x)-r<d(a, x)-d(a, y)$. By triangle inequality, we have $d(a,x)\leq d(a, y)+d(y, x)$ and so
$$d(a,x)-r<d(a, x)-d(a, y)\leq d(x,y).$$
This gives the result. Why must we assume $x\not\in B(a ;r)$?

Comment: If $x\in B(a;r)$ then the statement $d(a,x)-r\le d(x, B(a;r))$ is also true, but trivially so (or, let me say, it allows for a trivial proof), as the left-hand side is $\le 0$ and the right-hand side is $0$. Thus, this statement is true regardless of whether $x\in B(a;r)$ or $x\not\in B(a;r)$, but it is worth only proving in the latter case.